# Javascript not executing immediately, delayed until a second after page load

Tags: javascript, html, clock

After a quick cobbling together of a clock app to test the JavaScript linking ability of my Flask App hosted on Heroku, I'm stumbling on the clock text not immediately filling the .innerHTML of my element.

Javascript:

```
// This sets our ticker to execute the function once a second.
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
    myTimer();
}, 1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

The HTML is very simple, just a small h4 element with the id of "clock". I've tried `document.onload` as well, but whatever I try, the website loads with an empty element then fills it about one second later.

While I have your attention, why is the standard procedure for setting an interval declaring it as a variable? Is it for later reference in the program? Would it work as a naked `setInterval(xxxxx);`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's the whole point of `setInterval`, it runs the function after a delay.

Comment: Why do you use `setInterval()` if you don't want it to be delayed for 1 second?

Comment: The answer to your second question is yes. You can use the variable in a call to `clearInterval()` if you want to cancel the timer.

Comment: @Barmar, that's what I was thinking was the problem, but as I put a ```myTimer();``` above it in the program, it also wasn't executing it until after about a second had passed.

The ```setInterval()``` is for updating the clock text every second, if there's a better way, I'd love to know it!

Comment: And thank you for the explanation of why I should be defining it as a variable!

Comment: When you try to run it without setInterval, is there any error in the console?

Comment: Placing a call to myTimer on the top won’t solve the issue? Maybe because the #clock element is not yet ready. Try to place the invocation in the right moment (document.onLoad could be an option) or maybe use setTimeout (with interval set to 0) to push initial execution in the event queue.

Comment: I've never seen `document.onload`, it should be `window.onload`.

Comment: And if the problem is incorrect placement, you should get an error saying that it can't assign `innerHTML` of `null`.

Comment: I've switched over to ```window.onload```, and using the fix below it seems to be working better. Thanks for the answers and ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval runs the funtion after a specified delay, if you would like to display time on window load for example, you could call your function once in `window.onload`. Declaring as a variable is needed if you would like to clear the interval, I added a button as an example.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    myTimer();
}

const btnStop = document.getElementById("btn-stop");
btnStop.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('stopped');
  clearInterval(myInterval);
})


var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
  myTimer();
}, 1000);


function myTimer() {
  var d = new Date();
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
```

```html
<p id="clock"></p>
<button id="btn-stop">stop</button>
```

Comment: It's definitely become much quicker through this fix! There's now a lag of a fraction of a second, where the placeholder text I put in still shows before the clock loads. I may just remove that and let the blinking in of the clock be part of the webpage loading. Thank you for your help and for the button idea!

Comment: The placeholder text will only change when the js is loaded which will always be a short time, you could for example start your clock on a button click and display the time only then. If the placeholder text doesn't have any meaning I would throw it out.